# Adding unique key to li tag in Clojure and Hiccup using a word and index as key

Tags: html, clojure, clojurescript, hiccup

I have a quick question. I'm working on a Clojure project. I want to add unique key to each li tag, like this:

```
(defn test [text]
    [:li {:key :index} text])
```

How I can set keys like "**hi+index**"?

I tried

> {:key (str "hi" index)}

but it does not working. I'm new to Clojure and hiccup.

Thank you very much.

Comment: In your `str` attempt there's `index` and not `:index`. But just using a vector should work, e.g. `["hi" :index]`.

Answer (score 0):

You are making a mistake somewhere.  When in doubt, ask the computer with some test code:

```
  (doseq [idx (range 5)]
    (prn (str "hi-" idx)))
```

with result

```
"hi-0"
"hi-1"
"hi-2"
"hi-3"
"hi-4"
```

I like to use [this template project](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template) for quick tests like the above. Just clone it and throw some sample code into the `test/clj/tst/demo/core.clj`
file, and away you go!